# Formulating equation for two mutual exclusive integers

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have a problem with formulating non-binary linear equation with mutual exclusivity

\begin{cases}
x_1 \gt 0, \quad \text{OR} &x_2 \gt 0 \\[2ex]
x_1 + x_2 = 300
\end{cases}

As the result I want the equation to have only two possible solutions $x_1 = 300$ or $x_2 = 300$.

Comment: The region $x_1 > 0 \ \mathrm{or}\  x_2 > 0$ is not bounded by linear inequalities.  This is not a linear programming problem.  (The region is two disjoint open quadrants of the $x_1$-$x_2$ plane.  No set of linear constraints can select this region.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to solve this as an LP. But we can solve this as a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) problem:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
x_1 \le 300 \delta \\
x_2 \le 300 (1-\delta) \\
x_1+x_2 = 300\\
\delta \in \{0,1\}\\
x_1,x_2 \ge 0
\end{array}
$$

To be complete: some MIP solvers also allow socalled SOS1 variables which do a similar thing.

Answer (score 2):

$$x_1\cdot x_2=0, \quad x_1+x_2=300$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, $x_1 * x_2 = 0$ doesn't look like a linear equation and as far as I know it's going to be a problem to solve it with standard linear-programming algorithms, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RustyRobot No, you are not wrong. So, I missed the "linear" in your post. I will give it a try to find a linear set of equations.

Comment: @RustyRobot What do you mean non-binary?

Comment: I found how to implement OR if $x_n$ is $0$ or $1$, in my case I need $x_n = 0$ or $x_n \gt 0$

Comment: @RustyRobot Not exactly, you need again $x_n=0$ or $x_n=300$, which does not differ in principle from $x_n=0$ or $x_n=1$, or does it? But, I do not think that there is an easy way. If it is down to 2 variables, I would suggest: set $x_1=300, x_2=0$ and run your solver, then set $x_1=0, x_2=300$ and run your solver again.

Comment: It's differ in practice, because original equation is more complex. Thank for helping me, as Erwin suggested I'll look into MIP or as you suggested will create a system on top of solver in order to rerun it.